# Eclipse: Using "Open Declaration" ... in a Scala project

Tags: scala, eclipse-plugin

I've been trying to convert from Java to Scala for a few months, and found that the greatest roadblock is that Eclipse plugin for Scala is hardly better then using Vim.

I normally have "Build Automatically" on, so apart from Open and Save, the commands I use most of the time are:

```
Open Declaration (F3)
References > Workspace (Ctrl-Shift-G)
Open Type Hierarchy (F4)
Open Type (Ctrl-Shift-T)
Content Assist (Ctrl-Space)
```

and looking at the Outline.

None of this works with the Scala IDE for the libraries. Some stuff works for my own code, like outline. But the rest just returns the following error:

> The resource is not on the build path of a Java project.

Is there any way to get any of those things to work in Eclipse? Without them, basically the only thing I get is syntax highlight and compile-on-save, and I can get syntax highlight from vim without needing 1.5 GB of ram...

With implicits, and static function import, finding out from where something comes is really difficult without F3. I ended up using Google to find what class/trait defines what.

[EDIT] I just pulled Eclipse Classic 3.6.2, and [update-1.0.0-milestones-2.8.1.final](http://download.scala-ide.org/update-1.0.0-milestones-2.8.1.final), which wasn't available the last time I checked. They have fixed the Outline, and "Open Type", that's it. The rest still doesn't work.

Comment: The plugin got completely rewritten, and the new one will probably see a simultaneous (or nearly so) release with Scala 2.9.0. This update you got has backports of stuff written for the new plugin, but it is still limited by design. If you are keen on Eclipse, you should migrate to the 2.0.0 beta releases, together with Scala 2.9.0 release candidates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of the Eclipse plugin are you using? If the version is from a while ago, then you're right, it's a bit buggy.

However, there is a new version, currently in beta (as of 23.04.2011) available from [Scala IDE Eclipse download site](http://download.scala-ide.org/). This is a lot better.

Also, please make sure that the 'Use JDT content assists' checkboxes are checked in Scala->Setup diagnostics window.

Please try the new version, and see if it fixes your problems. If not, raise a [bug](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Bug_Reporting), and the team will fix it.

Comment: I ran the update, like you said. I don't have automatic update on because I hate reinstalling Eclipse, and the automatic updates likes to break Eclipse several times a year. Unfortunately it did not change anything. Are you saying that those things actually work in your Eclipse?!?

Comment: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. 
Version: Helios Service Release 2 (x64 Windows)
Build id: 20110218-0911. 
I need the Web stuff because I want to use Lift.

Comment: I use the Scala IDE 2.0.0-beta2 with Scala 2.9.0.RC1 (http://download.scala-ide.org/releases/wip_experiment-2.0.0-beta2).

Everything apart from References->Workspaces works for me.