# Eclipse Scala IDE: can't open hierarchy for standard library classes

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

I have exactly the same problem as in this question: [Eclipse: Using "Open Declaration" ... in a Scala project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764126/eclipse-using-open-declaration-in-a-scala-project)

However, I'm using the latest [Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org/) in version 3.0.2 (I have downloaded the Eclipse bundle from the site), and I would assume such basic functionality works by now, and apparently it's me who have something misconfigured.

I have created a new Scala project. Then I open some standard library class/trait/whatever, let's say `scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers`. The source is neatly displayed, but when I try to show class hierarchy, I get the message: `The resource is not on the build path of a Java project`.

Also, searching for references etc. won't work.

I guess it is a matter of properly configuring the build path? Or maybe I should somehow attach Scala library sources to my project? But I can see the source, so aren't they attached already?

Here is the snapshot of my project configuration:

[image: Project outlook]

**UPDATE**:

By playing a bit with setting/resetting build path stuff, I managed to get rid of pop-up warning but the class hierarchy comes up empty and when searching for references I get only hits from my own sources, nothing from standard library.

In another workspace I also tried randomly adding and removing scala-library jars and got it work almost, but the type hierarchy comes up only with super-classes, without any sub-classes (which renders it quite useless). Searching for references works ok though.

Funny thing, I cannot make it work in my original workspace...

Gotta love Eclipse.

Comment: Can you attach a snapshot of your project hierarchy here in the post ? I want to see how your project is configured in the IDE. Make sure that the libraries are all visible in the snap

Comment: @SaifAsif what do you mean by "project hierarchy"? How can I display it?

Comment: The `Package Explorer` in the Scala-IDE. I want a snapshot of that.

Comment: @SaifAsif here you go

Comment: Thats exactly I needed and I think I see your problem. Writing answer below

Answer (score 1):

Your build path is not configured properly.

If you take a look under `Scala Library[...]` you have `scala-library.jar` we can only see one top-level package `scala`. There should be numerous other packages besides that. ***(Ruled Out)***

I would recommend you follow these steps

1. Right-click project, build-path, Java-build-path, Libraries and make sure that the correct library is referenced there.
2. If it is the one you need, Try to remove this library and add it again, then `clean` and re-fresh the project. Also try this step in a fresh workspace.(something must have messed up this workspace )
3. Lastly. Goto the `path D:\Eclipse For Scala\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\286\1\.cp\lib` and verify the sizes of the jars there. There should be 6 jars there and the size of scala-library jar should be around 6.8M. If size is smaller, consider re-downloading

Comment: I haven't yet tried to do what you are proposing here, but just a quick question for now: are you sure there should be anything more besides `scala` package? Because I have turned on the `hierarchical package presentation`, and there indeed are many more packages, but they are collapsed under the top-level `scala`. What else should be there?

Comment: I haven't got much luck with that... I got rid of the popup but little else (see my question update).

Comment: I see , so we can rule out the possiblity of missing/incomplete library. But the issue of build path still remains. Can you write the steps how you are creating your scala project and how exactly are you specifying the Scala library on the build path ?